# ANSI JOINS and UNIONS are not letting me use ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION of RTMVs

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

I'm trying to create a Real Time Materialized View. My Query contains Left Outer Joins. These Left outer Joins did not let me use `ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION` feature of *Real Time Materialized View*. I replaced joins with `UNION` that also is not executable with `ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION`. Does any one has any idea how to get pass it?

My Sample Query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW “MV_XYZ” 
(set of columns names associated with the parent tables used to 
create MV)
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS select "set of values associated from these 4 tables"
FROM abc_set ds, abc_d d
LEFT OUTER JOIN ab_case dc ON dc.c_id = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_lab dl ON dl.l_id = d.id
WHERE ds.id = d.d_id
AND d.ch = 1
AND ds.type = ‘ARC’;
```

I also have a MV_log for the above MV so that I can have real time data using FRESH_MV hint feature of 12.2 version

And Error I get 
    ORA-32361: cannot ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION for the materialized view

Comment: please paste some code samples.

Comment: Your version should be 12.2 to be able to use ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION. Is yours so..?

Comment: @Barbaros Yes its 12.2

Comment: Can you post the materialized view query that you are trying to create?

Comment: @Crazy2Crack I've added the query in Question Description

Comment: @Maciej Added the Query in question description

Answer (score 1):

One issue could be MV logs is not created for all the base tables. From Oracle docs:

> Ensure that materialized view logs exist on all the base tables of the real-time materialized view.

I have encountered the same issue `ORA-32361` when i was using only the static columns like below:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMP_DEPT_MV
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS
select e.deptno,e.SAL from emp e LEFT JOIN dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno; 

ORA-32361: cannot ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION for the materialized view
```

But when I added the aggregate columns, it worked without issues

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMP_DEPT_MV
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS
select e.deptno,sum(SAL) from emp e LEFT JOIN dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
group by e.deptno;
```

For more info please refer [**Using Real-time Materialized Views**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/advanced-materialized-views.html#GUID-0702359B-D379-4299-86C4-2958BCD4381D)

Comment: MV Log for base tables exist I've created MVlogs for base table first then I'm creating MV

Comment: Do you have aggregate column in the`select`? If possible can you post the column names also?